# What will be the working of this statement in program of java?

Tags: java, operators, increment, decrement

The Question is

```
if c=12;
c=c++ + ++c;
```

what will be the working solution for this?
like how would it be ex(12+13)something like this
please specify what would be (`c++`)and what would be (`++c`)

Comment: SO is not a site to do your homework for you. Tell us what you have tried to solve the question and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if c=12 then c++ + ++c is 12 + 14 = 26, so 26 will be assigned to c.
First the c++ is evaluated to 12 and then 13 is assigned to c. Then ++c first assigns 13+1 is 14 to c and results in 14. So we have 12 + 14 which is the result of the expression and is assigned to c again.

Comment: does the value of c at the point "c++" be 13, or it is initialized in the background as 13

Comment: Before "c++" c is 12. After "c++" c is 13. The result of the expression "c++" is 12.

Comment: To clarify: try this `System.out.printf("before %s, result %s, after %s", c, c++, c);` and you will get `before 12, result 12, after 13`